# confused in svg polygon points

Tags: html, svg, axis, shapes

I am learning about SVG and only the concept of the x, y-axis is confusing in it for me, because -

My code -

```
<svg height="300" width="500" class="menu-icon">

<polygon points="100 0 , 0 -100 , 150 -150" style="fill:red;stroke:black; stroke- 
width:4;" />

</svg>
```

And When I plotted these points on the graph

[image]

It's clearly a polygon(triangle).

I am a newbie in SVG so please help me!

Comment: your y axis is going the wrong way 0 is the top and positive is down. Replace all the negative y values with positive values and you'll see the triangle you expect.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In what order are SVG points plotted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70209132/in-what-order-are-svg-points-plotted)

Comment: Ya thanks a lot guys, I got my answer